# Java - Paint using class objects

Tags: java, class, jframe, paint

I am building a game for a class I'm working on and I need to paint some circles and rectangles. My problem is that there will be an unknown number of each the circles and rectangles, depending on user input. For example,if the user says `5`, there will be `25` circles. What I wanted to do was make a circle class and rectangle class so I could just change the x and y coordinates using a loop.

Is it possible to make such a class `"circle"` and class `"rectangle"` with a parameterized constructor (x and y coordinates) to accomplish this?

FYI - This is a pegboard game where you drop a ball on the top and the ball bounces off pegs until being caught in the rectangle holders. I believe the true name of this game is called pachinko. Similar to this image, but just a rectangle instead of a triangle setup.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b3B8qiXyTJ8/maxresdefault.jpg

Lastly, I must use only `swing` and/or `javafx` (which I am unfamiliar with)

Comment: See answer for your problem with respect to custom classes and creating instances. As for using Swing/Java FX, it would be difficult to write a solution for you. What have you tried so far? There are plenty of good Swing tutorials online which would help you.

Comment: Right now I simply have a jframe that requests user input between 5 to 10. Once the user clicks the okay button,  I am setting the current jframe instance visibility to false, then creating an instance of a GameWindow class. I have tried making a circle class where I use a method to grab the x and y variables, then those are passed to the paint() method, locoated in this sam circle class. Then I tried  calling the circle  class from the GameWindow class. I get nothing on screen. The GameWindow dow class is simply a blank jframe class.

Comment: Sorry it is hard to comment from my phone lol

Comment: Start with some abstraction, a rectangle and circle are shapes, they have position and size information and in your case, can be painted. Then you define your implementations, rectangle and circle, filling in the required functionality, namely the painting. Now you can keep them all in a List of "shapes", this is basically how the shapes API in Java works

Comment: Also, while you are thinking about abstraction - how does this game look from a more general level? Are circles and rectangles the proper abstractions? What is your model, what is your view, how users interact with that view and how does that modify the model? Maybe your model is a set of pegs with an area in some plane and a ball moving through that pane, ending in between particular pegs. So maybe the model is pin or ball and the view is displaying rectangles or squares representing those domain objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Guys, I figured this one out. For what I wanted to do, I simply had needed a paintComponent() method inside another class, then made my other class Ball() use this paintComponent() by requesting a Graphics object inside a my paintBall() method's parameters, then using this graphics object to paint my Ball class object. My answer seems wordy, but look at the Ball class below and you'll get it.

```
package main;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ball{

private int x = 5;  
private int y = 30;  

// This method will help to animate the current object,
// The xPos and yPos will change, then frame will be repainted
public void setPos(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
}

public void drawBall(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}
```

}

So basically, i just had to create an instance of Ball inside my main class, like so:

Ball myBall = new Ball();

myBall.drawBall(g); // where g is the graphics object from paintComponent() in the main class.

Answer (score 1):

You can, indeed, create classes for Rectangle and Circle, each with their respective x and y coordinates. Such a class might look something like this:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Rectangle(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

When you want to create a new instance of this class, you would simply use:

```
Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(0,25);
```

The above code would create an instance of `Rectangle` which has the x and y coordinates set to 0 and 25 respectively.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 1**

Your loop could then do something like this to initiate your rectangles in a loop as you suggested:

```
Rectangle[] myRectangles = new Rectangle[25];
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    x = x+25;
    y = y+20;
    myRectangles[i] = new Rectangle(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Maybe he is also asking how to draw separate classes onto the same frame as the main frame class??

Comment: Upon the user clicking the okay button on the first jframe class, I want to call the circle class to paint as many circles as needed onto the next jframe class... as well as the rectangles. The first jframe is simply to collect data. The second jframe will have all of the "paintings."

Answer (score 0):

NO YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG NEVER EVER EVER USE paintComponent();
Play around with this. 
    package pet;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;


public class pet extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
public pet() throws IOException{
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(870, 675));         //configuring panel
 addMouseListener(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JComponent newContentPane = new pet();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addMouseListener(new pet());
}
public void paintRectangleAtPoint(Graphics g, int x, int y, String shoutout){
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(x, y, 100,100);
System.out.println("See, you can send variables in, too "+ shoutout");
}
public void paintStuff(Graphics g, int x, int y){
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawOval(x, y, 100,100);
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
paintStuff(frame.getGraphics(),e.getX(), e.getY());
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
PaintRectangleAtPoint(frame.getGraphics(),100, e.getY(), "entered");
}
@Override
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: So why isn't this package more known then? It seems nice. Is it newer? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: Also I don't need to use the mouse at all, so this package seems like it would have unnecessary tools as well...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I just copied and pasted a convenient code from eclipse, have fun playing around with it though. I'm pretty sure this package is the same as calling repaint(), except it doesn't go through the repaint and straight to something that paints.

Comment: I was writing a physics simulator and ran into writing almost a thousand lines in my paintComponent to deal with different functions, I could have implemented it in an 8th of the time had I used multiple painting methods. the nice thing is, it can return a value, and accept variables as well as paint. Much more flexible than calling "repaint", thanks for calling me out on that one, I wasn't being very thorough. I'm new here.

Comment: LOL, that's okay - What matters is that I have a new playground :)